# How to use a OxyPlot Bar Chart inside a listview control for Xamarin.Forms IOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView with a binding template. And I have a list of PlotModels which I am using to bind to the list view.
And my PlotView is inside the template where I am binding the PlotModel to the PlotView.

Everything is running smooth in Android. But the problem is I am getting a error **"PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control."**.
when I am trying to run it on IOS.

//My content page

```
public MyConstructor()
{
List<MyChart> charts = new List<MyChart>();
charts.Add(new MyChart { PlotModel = PlotModel1 });
charts.Add(new MyChart { PlotModel = PlotModel2 });
charts.Add(new MyChart { PlotModel = PlotModel3 });
charts.Add(new MyChart { PlotModel = PlotModel4 });
ListView lvPlots = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RetainElement)
{
ItemsSource = charts,
ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(NewDashboardSubCell)),
HasUnevenRows = true
};
Content = lvPlots;
}
public class MyChart
{
       public MyPlotModel PlotModel { get; set; }
}
```

//My View Cell

```
public class NewDashboardSubCell : ViewCell
{
        PlotView plotView;
        public NewDashboardSubCell()
        {
            try
            {
                plotView = new PlotView
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    IsVisible = true,
                    IsEnabled = true,
                    HeightRequest = App.ScreenHeight - 100,
                    WidthRequest = App.ScreenWidth - 40
                };
                plotView.SetBinding(PlotView.ModelProperty, "PlotModel");
                View = plotView;                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[A PlotModel cannot be used in more than one view](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/plot-model.html). Create model for each item in the array an not just a view. But if it works on Android you might just need to clean install the app to get the changes if you already fix the issue.

Comment: I am using different plotmodel for different views. So there is no way of using a single plot model for more than one view. You can check my code.